# Use preg_match() and replace to converting URL to anchor tag in text

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, preg-match

I currently have the following code to add an `a href` to user-submitted plain text where `HTTPS://` is found. The problem is that this obviously changes all links in the text to the same `name/location`. How can I do this process seperately for every instance of `HTTPS://` in the text?

```
//Example variables (usually from MySQL)
$moreOrig = "https://duckduckgo.com is better than https://google.com";
// The Regular Expression filter
$testUrl = "/(http|https|ftp|ftps)\:\/\/[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}(\/\S*)?/";

if (preg_match($testUrl, $moreOrig, $url)) {
//split into parts if user has a /something to clean url
    $parts = explode ("/", $url[0]);

    //glue
    list($first, $second, $third) = $parts;

    //output
    $shortUrl = implode ("/", array($third));

    $more = nl2br(preg_replace($testUrl, "<a href='" . $url[0] . "' rel = 'nofollow'>" . $shortUrl . "</a>", $moreOrig));
  }
```

Output, desired vs actual ( assume input variable = "https://duckduckgo.com?q=Duck+Duck+Go is better than https://google.com?q=Duck+Duck+Go")

```
Desired:
<a href = "https://duckduckgo.com?q=Duck+Duck+Go">duckduckgo.com</a> is better than <a href = "https://google.com?q=Duck+Duck+Go">google.com.</a>
<br>
Actual:
<a href = "https://duckduckgo.com?q=Duck+Duck+Go">duckduckgo.com</a> is better than <a href = "https://google.com?q=Duck+Duck+Go">google.com.</a>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP: How can I make preg\_match match only the first occurrence?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30476674/php-how-can-i-make-preg-match-match-only-the-first-occurrence)

Comment: @GeorgeAppleton I think my question is different because I want to replace _all_ occurances, not just the first.

Comment: You can just put it in a loop, if you want to replace all occurrences how is that different to what you're doing now though? A desired input and output would be helpful I think

Comment: You can easily capture the link in the regex and use `$1` to put it back in where you use `$url[0]` now. However, to manipulate it to get a short url, you would probably need `preg_replace_callback()`.

Comment: Hi @JohnS. Can you show us what output you expect?

Comment: Here's a codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/wYVONm

Comment: Looks like you should be using `preg_replace_callback()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<?php declare(strict_types = 1);

$input = "
xxx
https://duckduckgo.com/url/foo
xxx
https://bing.com
xxx
https://google.com/
xxx
";

$result = preg_replace_callback(
    "@
        (?:http|ftp|https)://
        (?:
            (?P<domain>\S+?) (?:/\S+)|
            (?P<domain_only>\S+)
        )
    @sx",
    function($a){
        $link = "<a href='" . $a[0] . "'>";
        $link .= $a["domain"] !== "" ? $a["domain"] : $a["domain_only"];
        $link .= "</a>";
        return $link;
    },
    $input
);

echo $result;
```

Comment: The capture group around the whole pattern doesn't seem necessary.

Comment: Actually, there's no need for the callback. Just use replace with `$0` and `$2` in the replacement.

Comment: Right. Thanks!!

Comment: `\b` inside a character class means "backspace". Your negated character class will be better written as `\S` that means not a space (any kind of)

Comment: TIL. Thanks for the hint.

Comment: You can also reduce `(?:http|ftp|https)` to `(?:(?:ht|f)tps?)` that allows `ftps`. Nevertheless +1.

Comment: Thanks for the code. Can this be modified to fit the new example I just added to my OP, in which the input, https://domain.tld/xyz becomes <a href = "https://domain.tld/xyz">domain.tld</a>?

Comment: Updated the answer. Hope it's ok!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this easily with [`preg_replace_callback`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php).

```
<?php

//Example variables (usually from MySQL)
$string = "https://duckduckgo.com is better than https://google.com";

// The Regular Expression filter
$pattern = "/(http|https|ftp|ftps)\:\/\/[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}(\/\S*)?/";

$result = preg_replace_callback($pattern, function($match) {
    $url = $match[0];
    return sprintf('<a href="%1$s">%1$s</a>', $url);
}, $string);

// Result:
// "<a href="https://duckduckgo.com">https://duckduckgo.com</a> is better than <a href="https://google.com">https://google.com</a>"
```

Answer (score 0):

You does not need to use `preg_match()`, `explode()` and `implode()`. Just use `preg_replace()`. You need to use a group match for whole of url to replacing it by `<a></a>`

```
$testUrl = "@((https?|ftps?)://([\w\-.]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3})(/\S*)?)@";
$newStr = preg_replace($testUrl, "<a href='$1'>$3</a>", $moreOrig);
```

Check result in [demo](https://3v4l.org/RVfSm)